# How do I get Hellow Quantum world to run in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: q#

This is my first attempt at Q#. I followed the instructions here:  How do I get the missing dependencies? Please see my screen shot

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/install-command-line-qdk?tabs=tabid-vs
[image]

Comment: I reinstalled Visual Studio Community 2019 from scratch to see if it would install without 5.0.300 sdk.  It installs it automatically and does not look in the 3.1.409 directory when you build the Default Q# application.  I am not sure if this is the problem. The BasePath when I do dotnet --info is set to the 5.0.300 directory.  This is my first time trying to build a Q# program and I am really surprised that the instructions to get hello quantum world working are flawed since I have tried to follow them twice now according to the link above with the same result. Hard to get started Microsoft!

Comment: Can anyone try these instructions and see if they get the same result? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/install-command-line-qdk?tabs=tabid-vs

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just building the program? Nuget dependencies are typically downloaded the first time you build the program?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The screen shot is the result of the build.   I am surprised that the Hellow Quantum World wouldn't just work out of the box.   I followed the directions in the link exactly.  I installed Visual Studio 2019, then dotnet-sdk-5.0.300.  Then Microsoft.Quantum.Development.Kit-0.17.2105.14481.vsix.   Made a new Q# Application then clicked build.

Comment: When I try to restore nuget packages.  The first error I get is

Comment: When I try to restore nuget packages.  The first error I get is "Error occurred while restoring nuget packages:  The package is missing the required nuspec file.  Path: C:\User\Don\.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel\4.3.0

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using the most recent version of the QDK (0.17.2105.144881), so you can open your .csproj file and confirm that it's using it. You should see this on the first line:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk/0.17.2105144881">
```

You can also confirm that the NuGet.config file in your machine has the public feed in it:

```
  <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
```

If you still get NuGet restore issues, I would also recommend installing .Net Core SDK 3.1.409 ([Link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1)). I see that you are using .Net 5.0, but you can have multiple versions side by side.

I hope this information is useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I checked <Project Sdk="Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk/0.17.2105144881"> and  <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />  I also installed .Net Core SDK 3.1.409 as you suggested.  My problem remains the same.

Comment: This is my error when I build.  It is still looking for 5.3.0 sdk.  Is there a way to tell it to look for 3.1.409? 
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The package is missing the required nuspec file. Path: C:\Users\Don\.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel\4.3.0
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'C:\Users\Don\source\repos\QSharpApplication1\QSharpApplication1\obj\project.assets.json' not found.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is an issue with NuGet. If you in Visual Studio select Tools=>Nuget Package Manager=>Package Manager Console and in that write the command: **dotnet restore**.
And you then get an error similar to:

> The package is missing the required nuspec file. Path:
> C:\Users\x\.nuget\packages\x.x.x

Then there is something broken with your local NuGet cash, empty it by removing everything inside the packages folder. and then run the command **dotnet restore** again.

also includes the error messages, since image-texts isn't searchable (so that others also can find this):

> No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.Canon" exists.
> No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic" exists.
> No type with the name "EntryPoint" exists in any of the open namespaces.
> No identifier with the name "Message" exists. Assets file
> 'c:\User…\obj\project.assets.json' not fount. Run a Nuget package
> restore to generate this file.

Comment: This is the only one of the "answers" that actually answers the question and provides a working solution that resolved this issue for me.