# VS2019 Community Edition Q# Application Hello World Reference problem

Tags: q#

I am a Q# Beginner.
Using Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.4. Community Edition

Dotnet 5.0.401

Using the Q# Application Template I create a new   Q#  'Hello World' Application.
The Packages list entries all have a yellow triangle. (See Solution Explorer Image)

Building the project produces errors as expected.

The packages belong to the QDK.

[Solution Explorer View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqqWs.png)

I have spent many hours re-installing my Visual studio, the QDK and chasing down paths and tips which have not solved the problem.

I must be missing something fundamental.

Appreciate anything that can get this going.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on Mariia Mykhailova's answer as I don't have sufficient rep with my private login but the link 'this answer' led me to the solution.

It was a nuget problem.

As instructed I ran 'dotnet restore'

This gave an error
So I deleted Users\myname.nuget\packages\quantum\xxx.

This didn't fix it but the erroring file in the 'dotnet restore' changed.
So I deleted that file and its friends.

Again no fix but the erroring file changed.

So I played 'whackamole' repeatedly until finally dotnet restore was successful.

Reminds me of the good old days of dll hell.

Thought we were past all this BS but there you go.

The last delete that fixed the problem was Users\myname.nuget\packages\microsoft.csharp

I could have blitzed the whole packages directory I suppose but I am a timid mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [installation instructions for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/install-command-line-qdk?tabs=tabid-vs), you need to make sure you have .NET Core 3.1 installed, and Visual Studio 16.3 or greater.

If you still get NuGet packages restore issues after that, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67831975/how-do-i-get-hellow-quantum-world-to-run-in-visual-studio-2019) for some suggestions on how to deal with that.